# How to best implement a responsive image size in an Angular app

Tags: css, angular, sass, responsive-design, media-queries

I have created a card component in Angular. This component shows a profile picture, the size of which I want to change depending on the screen size of the device my app is running on. Knowing no better, I have tried to achieve this using media queries.

First of, my index.html contains the following important entry:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

The SCSS file of my card component contains the following media queries:

```
img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;

  @media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) and (max-device-width: 1920px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-device-width: 1920px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

Now, I am reviewing the result on three different monitors:

1. a 14'' notebook of 1920 x 1080
2. a 27'' monitor of 1920 x 1080
3. a 27'' monitor of 2560 x 1440

The second media query works fine: The image on my 2560 x 1440 monitor is larger than on my notebook. However, the first media query does not seem to work properly:

I have changed the `(max-device-width: 1920px)` to `(max-device-width: 1600px)` and nothing changes! I was expecting the image to become larger, i.e. to be of size 250px x 250px, but it remains 200px x 200px.

I cannot explain this behavior and am generally curious as on how to best implement this behavior anyways.

List item

Answer (score 1):

To check responsiveness on different devices and how items are view on different screen sizes, you can use your browser's Developer Tools. Here's a Chrome specific guide to test to see if your design is responsive: [Link](https://docs.inductiveautomation.com/display/DOC80/Test+Your+Responsive+Design+Using+Chrome%27s+Developer+Tools). You can google for other browsers if you don't use chrome.

And to answer your question about image responsiveness, setting the width and height to specific sizes makes them unresponsive and requires those media queries. The less media queries needed in your code, the better. To make your images responsive without media queries, use max-width and set your width to 100%; this way, you can set the size on your biggest device and when the image's container starts to get smaller, the image will shrink and be responsive.

Also, to keep the aspect ratio of your image consistent and responsive, it is best to only set either width or height. Then set the other to auto.

Ex:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps!